# How do I adjust the Windows 7 volume control over a smaller range?

Tags: windows-7, audio, headphones

I am currently using the Microsoft High Definition Audio driver provided with Windows 7 rather than the Realtek driver. When playing sound through my computer speakers (plugged into the rear panel jack), I set the volume control to 80. However, my headphones (plugged into the front panel jack) require a volume setting of at most 4.

[image: Volume control set to zero]

Windows will remember this setting when I plug/unplug the headphones, but the design of the volume control makes fine-grained volume control impossible (making me wish I had the "Wave/PCM" slider from Windows XP/Linux). Even a volume setting of zero results in clearly audible sound. Is there a way to "zoom in" on the lower part of the volume slider to better control the sound level from my headphones?

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe this is possible with the default Windows 7 audio controller [[see this]](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/how-to-change-the-volume-adjustment-step/a7c25403-4c69-4b74-b5a5-2320e6b675d0). However third party plugins such as [Volumouse](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/volumouse.html) or Volume2 can give smaller steps.

Volumouse is pretty basic and should fit your needs, though Volume2 supports more advanced features, such as changing the scale to logarithmic.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Volumouse works in Windows 7 and can very finely control volume with hotkey support.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the up and down arrow keys instead of the mouse.

Comment: That's what I did to get the volume settings of 0 and 4; I'm looking for a way to get more than five different settings (and lower settings than 0).

Comment: Then there isn’t a way to do it with the built-in volume control. You’ll need to get a third-party tool that can allow your to set the volume using different methods. You can probably find something you’ll like with Google, maybe even one with hotkey support. `;-)`